# scaleX of CCSprite on a CCBatchNode looks like total trash?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a line which I am scaling just the X of the sprite down to 23%...  If I do this in a graphics program, it looks fine:

[image]

However, if I do this in cocos by saying scaleX = 0.23; I get:

[image]

Why is cocos making this look like trash?  Is there anything I can do to fix this?  I tried doing mipmapping, but that only smoothed it a little, it still looks horrible.

Note, the way this is being rendered is:

```
ccnode (main container)
  ccspritebatchnode
    ccsprite (container, scaled 0.5)
      ccsprite (container, unscaled)
        ccsprite (actual sprite, scaled 0.23)
```

So I suspect this has something to do with using multiple levels of nested ccsprite containers with their own scaling.

I am using cocos2d v2.x

**UPDATE**: this has nothing to do with CCSprite containers.  I tried adding this directly to a CCNode and it looks like the exact same garbage.  Can someone PLEASE help?

Comment: Is this a `png` or some sort of `pvr` ?  Most pvr's use some fancy compression that may not survive well to any kind of spatial processing.

Comment: agh, you're right.. I tried a png and this no longer happens...  thank you!!!

Comment: glad this helped, been bitten once, took me days (weeks?) to understand these artefacts.